# Extend postActivity

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to post activities with custom datetimes.

From what I see in ActivityPostServiceImpl.java, datetimes are created there, and cannot be customized.

Here's a snippet of the code there:

```
try {

    Date postDate = new Date();
    ActivityPostEntity activityPost = new ActivityPostEntity();
    activityPost.setUserId(userId);

    activityPost.setSiteNetwork(tenantService.getName(siteId));
    activityPost.setAppTool(appTool);
    activityPost.setActivityData(activityData);
    activityPost.setActivityType(activityType);
    activityPost.setPostDate(postDate);
    activityPost.setStatus(status.toString());
    activityPost.setLastModified(postDate);
```

I would like to pass custom datetimes to activities, can be through the activityData object. Yet, I can't make Alfresco to load my new class (which extends ActivityPostServiceImpl) on the beans.

Any help?

Comment: Are you getting errors? How is your bean defined?

Comment: I managed to solve it, will post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to create a new CustomActivityPostService.java file, where I could extend a postActivity method to have an additional date parameter, and then modify the beans to user that service instead of the default ActivityPostService.